# How to point to other JAVA version in RAD eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, generics, ibm-rad

I saw that this has been asked before but in a way different situation than mine.
Anyway, originally the Java version that was used by my RAD was 1.3, I also pointed originally my JAVA_HOME to the 1.3 which is located here : C:\IBM\SDP70\jdk

Now I changed my JAVA_HOME to: C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_34
and my CLASSPATH to: C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_34\bin
and added the CLASSPATH to my PATH.

So, when I check my java version in cmd it is 1.6.
These info might not be related but I stated it anyways.

As for the eclipse of RAD, Under preferences > Java > Compiler:

```
*JDK Compliance
Compiler compliance level: 6.0
checked - Use default compliance settings
Generated .class files compatibility is 6.0*
```

and for installed JREs :

```
*checked - Java 1.6 Location - C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_34*
```

Sorry I cannot paste an image here yet.

BUT still when I run my program using generics, I still received this problem.

```
C:\IBM\SDP70\runtimes\base_v61\profiles\AppSrv01\temp\SGSETSCIMPB501Node01\server1  
\cimwebEAR\cimweb.war\prodctl\_login.java : 91 : The type List is not generic; it 
cannot be parameterized with arguments <Map>JSPG0091E: An error occurred at line: 22 
in the file: /prodctl/login.jspJSPG0093E: Generated servlet error from file: /prodctl
/login.jsp 

C:\IBM\SDP70\runtimes\base_v61\profiles\AppSrv01\temp\SGSETSCIMPB501Node01
\server1\cimwebEAR\cimweb.war\prodctl\_login.java : 91 : Syntax error, parameterized 
types are only available if source level is 5.0
```

I think it is still pointing to 1.3 and I don't know how to change it now.

Comment: Eric B. and I apparently answered at the same time.  His answer is much better than mine (IMHO).  Please check out his advice, and let us know what you find.  Be sure to accept his answer if it works for you!

Answer (score 2):

A few things you can check:

1. Check the eclipse.ini for a -vm argument.  It may specify a different VM.  However, this is just the VM that is used to launch eclipse and not necessarily the one that is being used for your project.
2. Check that your Preferences -> Installed JREs has your 1.6 jdk set as the default
3. Check the build path libraries for your project (you may have another JRE being used as the project JRE)
4. You don't specify if this is a maven project.  If so, you might have some settings in your pom.xml that specifies that it is a 1.3 JRE

Comment: Hi Eric,Thank you for your reply, apparently this is what the .ini contains, -vm
C:\IBM\SDP70\jdk\jre\bin\javaw.exe
-vmargs
-Xquickstart
-Xms40m
-Xmx768m
-Xgcpolicy:gencon
-Xscmx96m
-Xshareclasses:singleJVM,keep
-Xnolinenumbers
-XX:MaxPermSize=512M

I dont specifically know what does this mean.
As for everything else, I checked and they all matched the same java version which is 1.6.

Comment: That implies that you are using C:\IBM\SDP70\jdk\jre\bin\javaw.exe as your JVM for RAD itself; not necessarily the project.  If you right-click on the project and go to Properties->Java Compiler what is listed for "Compiler compliance level"?  Is the "Enable project specific settings" enabled as well?

Answer (score 2):

IBM RAD Developer is basically Eclipse-on-steroids.

You should be able to change your Java by changing Preferences > Java > Installed JREs

I don't have my copy of RAD Developer available at the moment, so I'm afraid I can't help you much further.

'Hope that helps...

Answer (score 2):

No idea about **RAD**. But if RAD is built-in on top of Eclipse then there are couple of things that you should try

1. check your [eclipse.ini](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini) file. You can specify the **VM** in the ini file. For example

   -vm
   C:\IBM\SDP70\jdk
2. Point 1 is the solution if your eclipse is giving you a problem. But its actually the compiler which is being used by eclipse. So you gotta do 2 things.
3. First, Preference > Java > Installed JRE > (Add new JDK) > (Standard VM 1.x) something > and point to your IBM JDK
4. Then go to your project build path and make sure that your JAVA Library in build tab is set as ur IBM JAVA SDK